# Convert special characters like äöü to aou (iconv)

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters, iconv

I'd like to convert special characters like äöü to aou. I tried `iconv('utf-8','ascii//TRANSLIT', 'äüö')`but this creates `"a"o"u`. How can I solve this?

Comment: That's how translit works... german Umlaute are not part of ascii, hence they are substitued ("transliterated")

Comment: @LarsStegelitz So how can I solve my problem?

Comment: result of translit depends on libiconv version (see remarks in the php docu of iconv). `var_dump(ICONV_IMPL, ICONV_VERSION);` to see which one you have. Mine (private) is "libiconv 1.15" and does the same `"a"o"u` BS, but on phpfiddle it's "glibc 2.17" and it's properly converting to "aeoeue". Aka: You need a better iconv implementation :)

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I'll try that tomorrow, thanks for the hint :). And btw, how can I achive a better iconv implementation? Sorry if this question is is dumb.. ;)

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't answer that question.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I solved the problem using `preg_replace` to remove all non alphabetic characters! ;)